# ASP.net core- handling custom error page with API controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have web application written with ASP.net core 2.2. This app has two parts:

1. MVC - serve HTML files.
2. API - expose API to angular application.

I was reading [this article](https://joonasw.net/view/custom-error-pages) and found that I can do it in this way:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if(ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !ctx.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        //Re-execute the request so the user gets the error page
        string originalPath = ctx.Request.Path.Value;
        ctx.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
        ctx.Request.Path = "/error/404";
        await next();
    }
});
```

Expected:

1. MVC controller will return custom error pages
2. API controller will return exactly what they coded for. No HTML.

Actual:

1. MVC - return custom error pages.
2. API - return custom error pages.

When I exposing APIs under this application, I dont want to return custom 404 HTML every 404 status code. API consumer don't need it.

How to solve it?

Comment: Where ist that code located, which controllers do you have and what URLs are you using to get these results?

Comment: Is MVC and API two separated projects? Or you use the MVC controllers as "API" controllers?

Comment: Just to be clear - it's a single project which contain MVC and API controller.